# Mysql insert statement where one value is given and on obtain from a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `area`(name, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$name',SELECT 'id' from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name')
```

What i am trying to do is insert a value (name= $name) which is obtained from a from and then the foreign key id of a certain hub which is obtained by the sub-query.

when I run this query i get the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 'id' from hub WHERE name = 'EASTERN_CAPE')' at line 1.

Is my query incorrect?  Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: I don't think you can use 'where' clause in insert

Answer (score 4):

Use `` ` `` around column_name, you are using `'` around `id` column_name. Also use `()` for inner query.

```
INSERT INTO `area`(name, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$name',SELECT 'id' from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name')
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO `area`(name, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$name',(SELECT `id` from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name'))
```

**Note :** Your code is wide open for SQL injection, use prepared statement OR escape them.

Comment: @Alwina Why are you not accepting answer after you get the result?

Answer (score 2):

Put the given value into the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO area (name, fk_hub_id)
SELECT '$name', id
FROM hub
WHERE name = '$hub_name'
```

Comment: Vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @PLB Not if the variables are properly escaped. Anyway, I'm not trying to solve every problem, just show him the correct SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `area` (name, fk_hub_id)
SELECT '$name',
       id
FROM   hub
WHERE  name = '$hub_name'
```